Can we create Staking Transaction or StakeProgram transaction using Version0?
The legacy staking program transaction is working fine, But I want to update to the transaction type Version0.
Below code created a transaction hash successfully, but transaction is not found in mainnet.
This the transaction hash
45Afjo37zgvk871q6vyzg2gjCQ3HPxdeRZ5MmQVFXJL32NMZYYWZnRjsdGDKSfwe3Rn6Cy8d7fDdASgb3uHPMTgB

Below Is the code
const prepareCreateStakingMessage = async ({
  fromAddress,
  amount,
  validatorPubKey,
  solanaProvider,
  privateKey,

}) => {
  console.log('fromasdas', fromAddress);
  console.log('validatorPubKey', validatorPubKey);
  const fromAddressPubKey = new PublicKey(fromAddress);
  const voterPublicKey = new PublicKey(validatorPubKey);

  const programPublicKey = new PublicKey(
    'Stake11111111111111111111111111111111111111',
  );
  const seed = nanoid();
  const stakeAccountPubKey = await PublicKey.createWithSeed(
    fromAddressPubKey,
    seed,
    programPublicKey,
  );
  console.log('staklkee', stakeAccountPubKey);
  const instructions = [
    ...StakeProgram.createAccountWithSeed({
      authorized: new Authorized(fromAddressPubKey, fromAddressPubKey), // Here we set two authorities: Stake Authority and Withdrawal Authority. Both are set to our wallet.
      fromPubkey: fromAddressPubKey,
      lamports: LAMPORTS_PER_SOL * Number(amount),
      stakePubkey: stakeAccountPubKey,
      basePubkey: fromAddressPubKey,
      seed: seed,
    }).instructions,
    ...StakeProgram.delegate({
      stakePubkey: stakeAccountPubKey,
      authorizedPubkey: fromAddressPubKey,
      votePubkey: voterPublicKey,
    }).instructions,
  ];
  const recentBlockHash = await solanaProvider.getLatestBlockhash('finalized');
  console.log('receneee', recentBlockHash);
  const   transactionMessage = new TransactionMessage({
    payerKey: fromAddressPubKey,
    recentBlockhash: recentBlockHash.blockhash,
    instructions,
  });
const secretKey = bs58.decode(privateKey);
  const fromKeypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretKey, {
    skipValidation: true,
  });
  const transaction = new VersionedTransaction(
    transactionMessage.compileToV0Message(),
  );
  transaction.sign([fromKeypair]);
  return await solanaProvider.sendTransaction(transaction);
};


Your transaction could have not been accept for many reasons, like congestion. Do you have any error info to show that there might be a problem with the construction of the transaction?

@JonC No, I don't get any error.
Do you have any code or documentation for creating a version transaction for staking?

Versioned transactions work just like normal transactions except they have slightly different constructors, so we don't have docs for that specific case. But in your case, it appears like you've done the right thing! It's probably an issue on the network, but you can double check on devnet or a local solana-test-valdiator. If those go through, then it's a congestion issue on mainnet
